# How to SUM columns in the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
id      pymt_no1     pymt_no2      pymt_no3    pymt_no4     pymt_amt1     pymt_amt2       pymt_amt3    pymt_amt4
25      100          5             150           50             60           70            80              90
```

How the table works is that pymt_no1 corresponds to pymt_amt1, etc...

What I am trying to do is, total up the pymt_amt columns based on a CASE statement where the pymt_no is between a range of values.

For example, I am trying to get the total pymt_amt where any of the pymt_no is between 100 and 150. So in this case for the table above, only pymt_no1 and pymt_no3 have a value of between 100 and 150, so I need to total the pymt_amt that corresponds to it, so the total here would be 140.

I have tried the query below, but my issue is that it is only pulling the first pymt_amt only and not the rest for me to add together:

```
with pymt as (
SELECT 
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN pymt_no1 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt01
        WHEN pymt_no2 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt02
        WHEN pymt_no3 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt03
        WHEN pymt_no4 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt04
        END AS [Amount]
FROM pymt
)


SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(Total) as [Total]
FROM pymt
GROUP BY id
```

My thought behind this process for the sample above was to for example in the cte, for it to look something like this:

```
id     Amount
25       60
25       80
```

And then with this stored in the cte, I could SUM the Amount column and group by the id column to get the correct total.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add case for each column

```
--Sample table and Data 
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id INT ,
    pymt_no1 int,
    pymt_no2 INT,
    pymt_no3 INT,
    pymt_no4 INT,
    pymt_amt1 INT,
    pymt_amt2 INT,
     pymt_amt3 INT,
     pymt_amt4 INT)

 INSERT #temp (   id ,
                  pymt_no1 ,
                  pymt_no2 ,
                  pymt_no3 ,
                  pymt_no4 ,
                  pymt_amt1 ,
                  pymt_amt2 ,
                  pymt_amt3 ,
                  pymt_amt4
              )
 VALUES (   25 , -- id - int
       100 , -- pymt_no1 - int
       5 , -- pymt_no2 - int
       150 , -- pymt_no3 - int
       50 , -- pymt_no4 - int
       60 , -- pymt_amt1 - int
       70 , -- pymt_amt2 - int
       80 , -- pymt_amt3 - int
       90   -- pymt_amt4 - int
   )



--Solution
with pymt as (
SELECT 
id,
 CASE  WHEN pymt_no1 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt1 ELSE 0 END AS AmOUNT1 ,
 CASE  WHEN pymt_no2 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt2  ELSE 0 END AS AmOUNT2 ,
 CASE  WHEN pymt_no3 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt3  ELSE 0 END AS Amount3 ,
 CASE  WHEN pymt_no4 BETWEEN 100 and 150 THEN pymt_amt4  ELSE 0 END AS Amount4 

 FROM #temp
 )


SELECT 
  id,
  SUM([Amount1] + pymt.AmOUNT2 + pymt.Amount3 + pymt.Amount4) as [Total]
 FROM pymt
 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of servicing this request is to use a series of union queries for each pair of columns. If your data matches your sample column size then this is a fairly quick way of achieving the result. You can then wrap you query with an outer query that sums your values

```
declare @pymt table  (id  int,    pymt_no1  int,   pymt_no2   int,   pymt_no3   int, pymt_no4 int,    pymt_amt1  int,   pymt_amt2    int,   pymt_amt3  int,  pymt_amt4 int);

insert @pymt (
id ,     pymt_no1  ,   pymt_no2   ,   pymt_no3   , pymt_no4   ,  pymt_amt1  ,   pymt_amt2    ,   pymt_amt3   , pymt_amt4)
values

(25  ,    100  ,        5       ,      150   ,        50   ,          60     ,      70   ,         80        ,      90);

select sum(amount_to_sum) from (
select pymt_no1, pymt_amt1 as amount_to_sum from @pymt where pymt_no1 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no2, pymt_amt2 from @pymt where pymt_no2 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no3, pymt_amt3 from @pymt where pymt_no3 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no4, pymt_amt4 from @pymt where pymt_no4 between 100 and 150) x;
```

If you really want to do it as a CTE then you can do so like this:

```
declare @pymt table  (id  int,    pymt_no1  int,   pymt_no2   int,   pymt_no3   int, pymt_no4 int,    pymt_amt1  int,   pymt_amt2    int,   pymt_amt3  int,  pymt_amt4 int);

insert @pymt (
id ,     pymt_no1  ,   pymt_no2   ,   pymt_no3   , pymt_no4   ,  pymt_amt1  ,   pymt_amt2    ,   pymt_amt3   , pymt_amt4)
values

(25  ,    100  ,        5       ,      150   ,        50   ,          60     ,      70   ,         80        ,      90);

with pymt as (
select pymt_no1, pymt_amt1 as amount_to_sum from @pymt where pymt_no1 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no2, pymt_amt2 from @pymt where pymt_no2 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no3, pymt_amt3 from @pymt where pymt_no3 between 100 and 150
union
select pymt_no4, pymt_amt4 from @pymt where pymt_no4 between 100 and 150)

select sum(amount_to_sum) from pymt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
select id,
    sum(
    (case when pymt_no1 between 100 and 150 then pymt_no1 else 0 end) +
    (case when pymt_no2 between 100 and 150 then pymt_no2 else 0 end) +
    (case when pymt_no3 between 100 and 150 then pymt_no3 else 0 end) +
    (case when pymt_no4 between 100 and 150 then pymt_no4 else 0 end)
    )
from pymt
group by id
```